# Можно ли парсить мобильные приложения на Python?

Tags: python

Есть мобильное приложение супермаркета, где можно посмотреть цены на товары и заказать их. Требуется получать данные об определенных товарах но нету публичного API. Можно ли в теории парсить мобильные приложения как сайты?

Comment: Можете попробовать узнать этот апи таким методом https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5ll4jyY6Yg

Answer (score 6):

приложение общается с сервером по сети интернет и если протокол HTTP, то ставишь BurpSuite, прописываешь адрес прокси в настройках сети телефона, хандлишь запросы приложения и анализируешь.
если не по http, что маловероятно, то ставишь WireShark, настраиваешь ПК с акулой как точку доступа, коннектишь телефон и сканируешь сетевую активность.